# What are System Dynamics Variables on MariaDB?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I'm a nweeby and i really didn't understand what is a Dynamic Variable. I didn't found on documentation. And really what is the concept of Dynamic Vatiables.

Comment: In what context did you see that term?

Comment: Here on Documentation (https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/server-system-variables/), every variable has a dynamic field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the MySQL/MariaDB server "VARIABLES":

- Dynamic: Yes -- You can `SET` the variable and immediately see the effect.
- Dynamic: No -- You need to change the configuration file (`my.cnf`) and restart the server.

That covers most cases; there are a few that are more complicated.  Also, there is some move toward making more of the Variables "dynamic", so you will see differences based on Version of MySQL/MariaDB.

Also, this is *usually* the history of the values:

1. When the server starts, the `GLOBAL` copy of the variables are set from `my.cnf` or formulas, etc.
2. When a user connects, the `GLOBAL` values are copied into `SESSION` copies.
3. If dynamic, `SET variable_name = value` changes the `SESSION` value.

`SET GLOBAL ...` will change the default value for all *subsequent* connections, *not* your current connection.  There are exceptions to this...

Some `VARIABLES` do not distinguish between `SESSION` and `GLOBAL`.  For example, since InnoDB's buffer_pool is shared among connections, most settings are `GLOBAL`; there is no separate value for each `SESSION`.

(Sorry if I digressed too much; it gets messy.  But usually you don't need to worry about these issues.)